# Find object in a list with multiple primary keys in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of n primary keys:

```
primary_keys = ['pkey1', 'pkey2', ..., 'pkeyn']
```

and I have a dict of key / values:

```
kw = {'pkey1': 123, 'pkey2': 456, ..., 'pkeyn': 789, 'other': 'abc', 'values': 'def'}
```

and I have a list of instances:

```
instances = [obj, obj, obj]
```

I want to find, in the list of instances, the one whose primary keys match the primary key values in my `kw` dict.

Is there an easy way to do this in Python?

**Note**: I'm pretty sure I won't have more than 2 PKs, but would like to allow for more, just in case.

Comment: I keep getting a few levels deep in nested for loops before getting stuck on actually getting the primary key values and comparing them to the instances primary keys.

Comment: What are your instances? Is it dicts whose keys can be values of kw? It's not clear to me.

Comment: @PhML  I agree we need more clarification on how you use the instances

Comment: "I want to find, in the list of instances, the one whose primary keys..." - say i is an element from instances, what do you mean by the primary key of i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work if there is exactly one instance that matches.

```
next(inst for inst in instances
          if all(get_key_value(inst, pkey) == kw[pkey] for pkey in primary_keys))
```

Where `get_key_value` is a function that return the value of the given key for the given instance.
If the keys are simple attributes of the instance you can use `getattr` instead, while if the instance is `dict`-like you can use `inst[pkey]`.

Example usage(instances simplified to their set of primary keys):

```
>>> instances = [{'a': 5, 'b': 3}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8},  {'a': -1, 'b': 19}]
>>> primary_keys = ['a', 'b']
>>> kw = {'a': 7, 'b': 8}
>>> next(inst for inst in instances
...           if all(inst[pkey] == kw[pkey] for pkey in primary_keys))
{'a': 7, 'b': 8}
```

If no instance matches the keys a `StopIteration` is raised, which you can easily catch with a `try` block. If you want to keep all the instances that match you can simply transform the above into a list-comprehension:

```
[inst for inst in instances
      if all(get_key_value(inst, pkey) == kw[pkey] for pkey in primary_keys)]
```

Comment: Thanks Bakuriu, for your detailed answer.  This works perfectly.

Comment: In addition, if I wanted to update the instances values with the remaining values in `kw`, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel You mean that `kw` has more keys then the ones listed in `primary_keys` and you want to update the instance that match to also have these keys? It depends on how the instances are implemented. If the instances keys are attributes you could simply find the instance with my solution and then do `instance.__dict__.update(kw)` to overwrite all the key attributes. If you can give me more details about the instances and their key fields I may be able to give you better advice.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
match = []
for instance in instances:
    if instance.key in kw:
        match.append(instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an actual working piece of code with a test:

```
primary_keys = ['pkey1', 'pkey2', 'pkey3']

kw = {'pkey1': 123, 'pkey2': 456, 'pkey3': 789, 'other': 'abc', 'values': 'def'}

def obj_matches(obj):
    for key in kw.keys():
        if key.startswith('pkey') and getattr(obj, key) == kw[key]:
            return True
    return False

class Foo(object):    
    def __init__(self, pkey1, pkey2, pkey3):
        self.pkey1, self.pkey2, self.pkey3 = pkey1, pkey2, pkey3

instances = [Foo(123, 0, 0), Foo(0, 456, 0), Foo(0, 0, 789), Foo(1, 2, 3)]

matches = []
for obj in instances:
    if obj_matches(obj):
        matches.append(obj)


for m in matches:
    print m.pkey1, m.pkey2, m.pkey3
```